# Where can I download JDK 1.6u20 64-bit?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android program for my senior capstone project, and having trouble getting the correct environment configured.  I'm using a 64-bit windows machine with Eclipse 3.5 and JDK 1.6u21.  From what I've been able to gather, Eclipse 3.5 doesn't play well with update 21 on 64 bit architectures, and it's recommended to use JDK 1.6u20.  Problem is, I can't find update 20 anywhere.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does play well, with 1.6.0_21b7 (build 7): read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 12):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html